# Why this java Class doesn't compile

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Why does the below java code compilation result in an error?  I'm using java 8, if that matters.

```
public class SimpleTest {

      private static boolean isPresent(int []... arrays, int number){

          boolean isPresent = true;

          for(int i=0;i<arrays.length;i++){
              //isPresent = doBinarySearch(arrays[i], number);
              if(!isPresent){
                  break;
              }
          }

          return isPresent;
      }    
}
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
SimpleTest.java:3: error: ')' expected
  private static boolean isPresent(int []... arrays, String number){
                                                   ^
SimpleTest.java:3: error: ';' expected
  private static boolean isPresent(int []... arrays, String number){
                                                                  ^
2 errors
```

Comment: varag parameters must be the last parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Varargs can only be declared as the last parameter.

> You can use a construct called varargs to pass an arbitrary number of
>   values to a method. You use varargs when you don't know how many of a
>   particular type of argument will be passed to the method. It's a
>   shortcut to creating an array manually.
>
> To use varargs, you follow the type of the **last parameter** by an
>   ellipsis (three dots, ...), then a space, and the parameter name. The
>   method can then be called with any number of that parameter, including
>   none.

([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html))

Answer (score -3):

This should work :

```
private static boolean isPresent(int []arrays, int number) {
...
}
```

Comment: This will give a compile error, and does not use varags like he wants to